# Stop VC++ debugger stepping into operator new

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

It's really annoying when stepping through code and everytime a new object is created, the debugger doesn't go straight to the constructor but through the CRT `new` operator in new.cpp:

```
void *__CRTDECL operator new(size_t size) _THROW1(_STD bad_alloc)
        {       // try to allocate size bytes
        void *p;
        while ((p = malloc(size)) == 0)
                if (_callnewh(size) == 0)
                {       // report no memory
                static const std::bad_alloc nomem;
                _RAISE(nomem);
                }

        return (p);
        }
```

Is there a way to selectively stop specific functions/classes getting stepped into, or some other way I can avoid this?

Comment: This is inevitable when you build with /MT, your program calls new, new calls the constructor.  Just set a breakpoint on the constructor you want to debug.  Debug + StepOut to quickly fix stepping oopses.

Comment: If I'm stepping through a function, that function might construct objects and I want to run throught the ctor logic... but having to SHIFT+F11 all the time is irritating. It's not the end of the world, just a pain :)

Answer (score 1):

Andy Pennell's blog entry "[How to Not Step Into Functions using the Visual C++ Debugger](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andypennell/archive/2004/02/06/69004.aspx)"  provides most of the answer.  I was trying to figure this out as well and through perseverance (or perversity I guess) I tried each letter of the alphabet until I got a hit with o.*=nostepinto.

From that, noticing in the Modules window it said msvcr100d.dll!operator new, led me to try "operator new.*" as the regular expression.

It worked!  The magic to put in for Andy's how to is "operator new.*=nostepinto"

n.b.  I was using VS 2010, but the same should work on VS 2008

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio has a feature where you can choose which function to step into. 
So if you have code like this:

foo* p = new foo( new baz ( new flip() ) );

You right click to bring up the pop-up menu. From there select 'Step into', and it will give you a list of functions you can step into. So here you can avoid all the new calls, and have your choice of which constructor you step into.